# The equal sign (=) gives error when importing to mocha in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, unexpected-token

I'm trying to set up a test environment for a product, using Node and Mocha. Everything seemed to be going smoothly, I had to use `--require esm` to ensure the named imports worked, but I still get unexpected token errors, this time on the first lines of a class. I have a static variable

```
class example{
    static element = -1;
}
```

And this gives me an error when using
    import {example} from "./example" in the test file.

My npm test script looks like this: `mocha --require esm`, which perfectly tests my normal classes, but as soon as I add a static variable to one of those, they also crash.

The actual error report looks like this:

```
[C/.../client]\src\example.js:2
    static element = -1;
SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
```

I've tried googling all sorts of answers, but they're mostly about not getting the named imports to work, which I do. If I have to set up a babel transformation (which I tried, but I don't think I did it correctly), what would the configurations be, and how could I run that with react-scripts/mocha?

Thanks for any answers on this!

Comment: `static` is for defining static methods, JS doesn't have static variables.

Comment: there is no such ```static``` in javascript

Comment: @Barmar [you sure about that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Class_fields)?

Comment: is your node version is 12+?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Missed that. But it's declared experimental, maybe his version of node.js doesn't support it.

Comment: @JuhilSomaiya - perhaps not in internet explorer .... :p

Comment: @PatrickRoberts The strange thing (I think) is that the program itself compiles and runs fine. It's when I test that everything fails. I just tried removing the static, but then there are places I can't access it. Right now the system is build on classes with static methods, should I remodel it to use constructors and access the methods and variables through instances? But then I couldn't keep variables throughout different modules? And across through to my server files. I tried using localstorage at one point instead, but that also failed. I don't remember why right now.

Comment: @AZ_ I just switched to version 12. I was apparantly using 10. This did not change anything. If I use engine{node: >=12.0} in my package.json, this should do it, right?

Comment: you need to have it installed in your system, check `node --version`.

Comment: What happens if you use babelify to make it "browser" compatible?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing my exported classes to exported functions, and get/set functions for variables instead of the static ones. It would probably have worked to do it with another version of node, or some babel transform, but at this point, this seemed like the best way for me.